# Server migration from GCM to FCM

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

We're looking to finally update our server to use Firebase Cloud Messaging since Google Cloud Messaging was deprecated and removed.  According to this question, [Migrate from gcm to fcm in the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477224/migrate-from-gcm-to-fcm-in-the-server), there shouldn't be much to do since the Sender() defaults to the FCM endpoint if it's empty.  However, no version with that change is available in Maven, the last one being 1.0.0 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gcm/gcm-server).  So...

Is there an official release out there for GCM that includes https://github.com/google/gcm/commit/b9e5624cd975d72bf2604d7f025cdd24bf2672d8?  Or do we have to build it from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see it in the Maven Repo, but [it's GitHub releases page](https://github.com/google/gcm/releases) itself has the [v1.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/google/gcm/releases/tag/v1.0-SNAPSHOT) available -- which contains the updates (that I think) you're looking for.

Comment: I saw that, but again it's just the source code in those releases, not a jar file.  So goes to my last question: do we have to build it from source?

Comment: Yes - at the very least it looks like it. Shouldn't be that much of a trouble -- unless there's a specific setup you need in it. To also answer "*Is there an official release out there for GCM...*" -- there is currently no official release after the last gcm-server update.

Comment: Btw, there's also the option to use [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) -- which has support for [Java for FCM related functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/package-summary) -- but it's not "*FCM-only*", if that's what you're strictly looking for.

Comment: Yeah, might have to end up using that.  Was hoping there was a migration guide for it if you're coming from GCM, but there isn't.